# How to render bitmap into canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, bitmapimage

I've subclassed `Canvas` so that I can override its `Render` function. I need to know how I can load a bitmap in WPF and render that to the canvas. I'm completely new to WPF and I haven't found any tutorials that show you how to do something so seemingly trivial. Step-by-step instructions with examples would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
class MyCanvas : Canvas {
   protected override void OnRender (DrawingContext dc) {
      BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage (new Uri ("c:\\demo.jpg"));
      dc.DrawImage (img, new Rect (0, 0, img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

In WPF it is a rare case that you would need to override `OnRender` especially if all you wanted to do was draw a BMP to a background:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources\background.bmp" />
    </Canvas.Background>
    <!-- ... -->
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do want to paint background of canvas, I would recommend using `ImageBrush` as `Background`, 'coz that's simple as you dont need to subclass `Canvas` to override `Onender`.

But I'll give you a demo source-code for what you have asked:

Create a class (I've called it `ImageCanvas`)

```
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Media;

    namespace WpfApplication1
    {
        public class ImageCanvas : Canvas
        {
            public ImageSource CanvasImageSource
            {
                get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(CanvasImageSourceProperty); }
                set { SetValue(CanvasImageSourceProperty, value); }
            }

            public static readonly DependencyProperty CanvasImageSourceProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("CanvasImageSource", typeof(ImageSource),
                typeof(ImageCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

            protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext dc)
            {
                dc.DrawImage(CanvasImageSource, new Rect(this.RenderSize));
                base.OnRender(dc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <local:ImageCanvas CanvasImageSource="/Splash.png">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello From Mihir!" />
        </local:ImageCanvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: confused.  how do I use this code?  If I have a bitmap 'b', what do I do to render it?  
` ImageCanvas.Render(b);`  does not work.