# Placing Bitmap in Canvas in C#

Tags: c#, canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to render bitmap into canvas in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168370/how-to-render-bitmap-into-canvas-in-wpf)

What I want is simple. I want to place a `BitmapImage` into a `Canvas` in C#. My app is based on WPF. I searched for this and I found similar questions, but I could not find what I'm looking for.

In short, I have this:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("c:\\xyz.jpg"));
```

And I want to put this in the canvas, the mean is not that important, it can be a rectangle or whatever.

Comment: @mbeckish that one is irrelevant, i think. adding just a bitmap image should not be that complex, the guy proposes to extend canvas class. i am looking for an easier solution, since I am working on an already-written code and I do not want to make huge changes.

Comment: @rooter there is another answer for that question, it sets the bitmap as background for the Canvas.

Comment: @rooter - Please add more specifics to your question so that we don't have to guess about what you would or would not find acceptable.

Comment: @Adriano that one also does not work, since I want to place it on a specific region, but not as a background picture.

Comment: add another canvas, place this one where you like in the canvas before and use the bitmap as background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BitmapImage` object cannot be positioned inside a `Canvas` because it's not a control. What you can do is to derive your own class from the `Canvas` and override the `OnRender()` method to draw your bitmap. Basically something like this:

```
class CanvasWithBitmap : Canvas
{
    public CanvasWithBitmap()
    {
        _image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\xyz.jpg"));
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        dc.DrawImage(_image,
            new Rect(0, 0, _image.PixelWidth, _image.PixelHeight));
    }

    private BitmapImage _image;
}
```

Of course you may need to expose the file path and coordinates inside the `Canvas` through properties. If you do not want to declare your own class just to draw a bitmap then you can't use the `BitmapImage` class directly. The control to display images is `Image`, let's try this:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"c:\xyz.jpg");
bitmap.EndInit();

Image image = new Image();
image.Source = bitmap;
```

Now you can put the `Image` control where you want inside the `Canvas`.

Comment: It seems like deriving is the only solution. Thanks.

Comment: @rooter no, it's not. If you have a lot of Image controls (with the same image) you may consider to derive to save little bit of memory but you can always use the Image control.